# Magento 2 Change Minicart Product Image from thumbnail to regular image

Tags: magento2, image, mini-cart, thumbnail

After editing the minicart for a couple of days now i've noticed that the images are smaller versions of the images that you would see on the product pages. This means as i'm upscaling them to fit a larger container they are losing quality.

The file containing the image reference is within `Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/image_with_borders.html` although the image src is set like so:

```
data-bind="attr: {src: src, alt: alt}
```

I don't really know how I would go about changing the image src but I imagine there is another file somewhere where this references to but I can't find it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

You can edit view.xml in the below path

> app/design/{Package}/{Theme-name}/etc/view.xml

add the below code in it

```
<image id="mini_cart_product_image" type="image">
            <width>100</width>
            <height>100</height>
</image>
```

you can change the image type and width/height as per your need

**type** - It means what type of image should display in the respective places in the frontend.

Explanation:

1. image – corresponds to the Base Image role
2. small_image – corresponds to the Small Image role
3. swatch_image – corresponds to the Swatch Image role
4. swatch_thumb – corresponds to the Swatch Image role
5. thumbnail – corresponds to the Thumbnail Image role

For more information [Look at this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Alright so I have added in the extra code, but how do I call the new image type as opposed to the original thumbnail that was set?

Comment: Have you placed the above code still doesn't work for you, if any other minicart if found in your view.xml remove it. @A.Fletcher

Comment: Yes, i've tried removing the other image id which was "mini_cart_product_thumbnail" and it has made no difference. I think the problem in my case might be because i'm juggling multiple themes so your fix may be the one just within a different file. I'll give the upvote! Cheers for the help

Comment: Worked or not ?

Comment: I've had to put it on hold for a moment as the website i'm working on requires attention in other places but i've read through your attached devdocs link and it all makes sense. I will update you once I can get back around to working on it. Cheers

Comment: Well 1.5 years later and in another job entirely, I can confirm this works as intended. I've just had to do the same task. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to receive something like this, Cheers Mate :)

Answer (score 4):

In this topic we will do How to Change Product Image in Minicart

```
Step 1: Create di.xml file

Step 2: Create Image.php file
```

Product image in minicart will getten to  show by function `doGetItemData()` in `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem` class but this function is protected, so we cannot use plugin on it. Instead, it extends from `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem` and use function `getItemData()`

First We need to create registration and module file as per structure of magento 2 then follow below steps.

```
Step 1: Create di.xml file
```

Create di.xml file in `app/code/[Name_Space]/[Your_Module]/etc/frontend`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
     <plugin name="Change_Product_Image_In_Minicart" type="[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart\Image" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>


Step 2: Create Image.php file
```

Create Image.php file in `app/code/[Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart`

```
<?php

namespace [Name_Space]\[Your_Module]\Plugin\Minicart;

class Image
{

    public function aroundGetItemData($subject, $proceed, $item)
    {

        $result = $proceed($item);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($result['product_id']);

        /* thum url */ 
        $storeManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); 
        $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
        $mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        if($product->getThumbnail()){
            $result['product_image']['src'] = $mediaUrl.$product->getThumbnail();
        }
        else{
            $result['product_image']['src'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, your answered helpful for me to find other issue. Thank you again